# Am getting an error while reading json data received. Am developing a UWP using C# which reads data from json

Tags: c#, json, win-universal-app

```
public class BMIRSProxy
{
    static string json_url = string.Format("http://localhost:8081/bmirs_2015/php_scripts/get_staff_members.php");
    public async static Task<StaffMember> GetStaffMember()
    {
        var http = new HttpClient();
        var response = await http.GetAsync(json_url);
        var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(StaffMember));
        var ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(result));
        var data = (StaffMember)serializer.ReadObject(ms);
        return data;
    }
}

[DataContract]
public class StaffMember
{
    [DataMember]
    public string first_name { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string last_name { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string title { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string profile { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string image_uri { get; set; }
}
```

Above is the class I created. but when I can the method `GetStaffMember` within a button created , no data is output. when I debugged I got two errors from the `MemomryStream` instance `ms` as below :

1. List item

> ReadTimeout = 'ms.ReadTimeout' threw an exception of type
>   'System.InvalidOperationException'

2. List item

> WriteTimeout = 'ms.WriteTimeout' threw an exception of type
>   'System.InvalidOperationException'

Below is the code i used to call the method `GetStaffMember`

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    StaffMember myStaffMember = await BMIRSProxy.GetStaffMember();
}
```

Your help will be highly appreciated because am stuck now

Comment: can you debug and also show us the value of the 'result' variable?

Comment: this is the result from the debugger : result = "\r\n[{\"first_name\":\"Bukenya\",\"last_name\":\"Micheal\",\"title\":\"Sales Manager\",\"profile\":\"The...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your JSON string is an array containing 1 element.
So let us deserialize as an array and select the only element for your data binding

```
public async static Task<StaffMember> GetStaffMemberAsync()
{
    var http = new HttpClient();
    var response = await http.GetAsync(json_url);
    var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    var data = (JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<StaffMember>>(result))[0];
    return data;
}
```

Comment: this is the raw JSON from the debugger : result = "\r\n[{\"first_name\":\"Bukenya\",\"last_name\":\"Micheal\",\"title\":\"Sales Manager\",\"profile\":\"The...

Comment: The first option failed to compile. The second option threw this error : Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'BMIRS.Models.StaffMember' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.

Comment: It looks like you get StaffMember list not just a single object. Try to change:
 var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<StaffMember>(result);
into this:
 var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<StaffMember>>(result);

Comment: Converting it to a list will give me issues since am interested in using the StaffMember object for data binding on the XAML page

Comment: @bukenyamicheal i have edited the answer to deserialize as an array but select only the first element after that, for your data binding to work